# Understanding the trace of three matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to solve this problem, and would like some help. Question 2 just states the Matrix A and Matrix B are square matrices of size n.

[image]

Here is my thoughts so far:

I have already proved that tr(AB) = tr(BA). So, if we let AB = X, and DA = Y, we can observe:

**2nd Option:**

tr(ABD) = tr(DAB) = tr(BDA)

(1) tr(XD) = tr(DX) = tr(BDA)

(2) tr(XD) = tr(DX) is for certain true

(3) We then have tr(ABD) = tr(YB) = tr(BY)

(4) tr(YB) = tr(BY) is for certain true

(5) Since tr(ABD) = tr(DAB) and tr(DAB) = tr(BDA), by the associative property, tr(ABD) = tr(DAB) = tr(BDA).

**Option 4:**

\begin{align*}
  \mathrm{tr}(ABD) &= \sum_{i=1}^n (ABD)_{ii}\\
    &=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n A_{ij}B_{jk}D_{ki}\\
\end{align*}

Is that all there is? Or are other answers true too

Comment: Note that because of commutativity of addition/multiplication, the first and third option imply that $tr(ABD)=tr(ADB)=tr(DBA)=...$ etc. i.e. that the trace is also commutative. This is in general not true for more than 2 arguments.

Comment: Oh, so would none of them be true? @JacobA

Comment: No - it looks like you have correctly proven (2) and (4). Note the distinction between (2) and my comment above. (2) is showing that only *cyclic* permutations of the matrices leaves the trace invariant, as opposed to any arbitrary ordering.

Comment: Please don't double-post – it wastes everyone's time.